# i can't close other windows

Tags: python, pysimplegui

so i'm trying to make a question asker program that is connected to an access database and i'm having a problem i have a main window and i can't close other windows that i open after this is the code

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pypyodbc
import random

sg.theme('darkgrey3')
conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\FUAD\Documents\Database9.accdb;')
main_menu = [
    [sg.Text('PROJECT 1',pad=(70,40))],
    [sg.Button('Add question',size=(10,3),key=('add_question'))],
    [sg.Button('ask question',size=(10,3),key = ('-AskQuestion-'))],
    [sg.Button('see all the questions',size=(10,3),key='-SeeAllTheQuestions-')]
 ]

window = sg.Window('project',main_menu)
while True:
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 cursor.execute('select * from Questions')
 questionslist = cursor.fetchall()
 sg.theme('darkblue')


 def see_all_the_questions(delete, set):
     layout = [
         [sg.Text('What you want to do?', key='-text-'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('X', key='-Cancel*SeeQuestions-')],
         [sg.Button('delete', key='-delete-'), sg.Button('set the question', key='-set-'),
          sg.Button('Cancel', key='-cancel-', visible=False)],
         [sg.Listbox(questionslist, s=(50, 25), key='-listbox-', enable_events=True)]
     ]
     window = sg.Window('Question list', layout)

     while True:
         event, values = window.read()
         if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
             break
         if event == '-delete-':
             delete, set = True, False
             window['-cancel-'].update(visible=True)
         if event == '-cancel-':
             delete, set = False, False
             window['-cancel-'].update(visible=False)
         if event == '-set-':
             delete, set = False, True
             window['-cancel-'].update(visible=True)
         if event == '-listbox-' and delete == True:
             cursor.execute(f'DELETE FROM Questions WHERE ID in ({values[event][0][0]})')
             cursor.commit()
         if event == '-listbox-' and set == True:
             print('setted')
 **def add_question(question):
     sg.theme('darkbrown')
     layout = [
         [sg.Text('please enter your question'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('X', key='-Exit-')],
         [sg.Input(key='-input-'), sg.Button('-Enter-')],
         [sg.Text('Your question successfully added to questions!', key='sccful', visible=False)]
     ]
     window = sg.Window('question adder', layout)
     while True:
         event, values = window.read()
         if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
             break
         if event == '-Enter-' and values['-input-']!='':
             print(questionslist)
             print(questionslist[-1:][0])
             question = (questionslist[-1:][0][0]+1,values['-input-'])
             cursor.execute('''
                         INSERT INTO Questions VALUES(?,?)''',question)
             cursor.commit()
             break**

 event,values = window.read()
 if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
      break
 if event == '-SeeAllTheQuestions-':
     see_all_the_questions(False,False)
 if event == 'add_question':
     add_question('')
```

in bold part of the code i'm trying to get information from user and when the user hits the enter i want to close that window but it just isn't what can i do

i tried to close the window

Comment: dude, make list of windows you created and close all when u want to close. here ur just slamming new window on same variable

Comment: Where is your code to close the window ? Python `break` or `return` statement won't close the window. It should be `window.close()` here.

Comment: ok in this senario it helped me thank you but i have another problem if i want to close the window i have to use pysimplegui's own closing commands WIN_CLOSED but i dont want to use this if you look through the cod you can see in see_all_the_questions function i have an "x" button key = '-Exit-' i want to use = that button to close the window i write this code if event == '-Exit-':
             window.close()      but it gives me problem that says                                           yo have tried 100 times to read a closed window. you need to add a check for event ==WIN_CLOSED

Comment: To close a window, call `window.close()`, then GUI closed, what's the next statement will be in your `while` loop ? `event, values = window.read()` ? but window already closed or destroyed here. So you need to break from your event loop and add another statement `break` after you close the window. That's why we have a statement `window.close()` after `while` block or event loop and `if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, '-Exit-'): break` in the event loop.

Comment: oh that worked very well thank you so much!